# How to show data from SQL server using JSP, Servlet,Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

How can i retrieve data from Database using Java servlet, Hibernate, JSP? Help me :)

File *StudentModel.java*

```
public class StudentModel {
private final SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
public List<Student> studentList()
{
    try{
        sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        List<Student> result = sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Student.class).list();
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

File *Index.jsp*

```
  <body>
    <% StudentModel sm = new StudentModel();%>
<c:forEach var ="student" items="<%= sm.studentList()%>">
    Id: ${student.Id}<br>
    name:${student.Name}
</c:foreach>
</body>
```

File *Student.hbm.xml* (file config mapping to property in DB)

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entities.Student" table="Student" schema="dbo" catalog="javaTest">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="Id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="Name" length="100" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your student list as a request object in your servlet like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    List<Student> students = new StudentModel().studentList();
    req.setAttribute("students", students);
}
```

then access this list in your jsp like this:

```
<body>
    <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
        Id: ${student.id}
        Name: ${student.name}
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

Your Student.java

```
public class Student{
    private String id; 
    private String name;

    private String getId(){
        return id;
    }
    private void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    private String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    private void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```